# how to get value by name from dictionary in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with column of company names and i need to find domain names of it and store it in the same csv file beside the company names

**code i have used so far**

```
import pandas as pd
import clearbit
import json
clearbit.key = 'your secret key'
df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")

saved_column = df['Company']
i=0
for data in saved_column:   

    n = saved_column[i]
    i = i+1
    domain = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
    print(domain)
    l = json.loads(domain)
    print(l['domain'])
```

**This code here gives domain names logo and name in json but how to take only domain**

***But this gives error***
`l = json.loads(domain)
 print(l['domain'])`
   **error:**
`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'NameToDomain'`

> The csv file looks like this

```
Company
‎Accenture
‎AND Digital
‎Accenture
‎Kite Consulting Group
‎Capgemini
```

> expected output

```
Company                 Domain
‎Accenture              accenture.com
‎AND Digital            and.digital
‎Accenture              accenture.com
‎Kite Consulting Group  None
‎Capgemini              capgemini.com
```

***The json looks like***

```
Name: Company, dtype: object
{'name': 'Accenture', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'domain': 'accenture.com'}
{'name': 'AND Digital', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/and.digital', 'domain': 'and.digital'}
{'name': 'Accenture', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/accenture.com', 'domain': 'accenture.com'}
None
{'name': 'Capgemini', 'logo': 'https://logo.clearbit.com/capgemini.com', 'domain': 'capgemini.com'}
```

Comment: The error is right, JSON loads requires a string value. Yours looks like a dictionary or an object already. Check the type and extract accordingly.

Comment: how to get the value of the domain in this json ?

Comment: I have not checked you code but I am dare to assuer that `clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)` does not return a string but an object of type `NameToDomain`. This is why you are getting this error.

Comment: Could you share a sample csv file?

Comment: @Vivek email id ?

Comment: Please upload it on a temporary file sharing site and share the url

Comment: @vipul-rao: [Read the docs](https://clearbit.com/docs?python#) to know how to extract the vlaue of the domain. Nontheless, it might be something like `l.domain`.

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/e7ee5d5f0670a8c3be96d7cb90982311.html

Comment: @kazbeel i tried it but nothing is working for me

Comment: This looks like a straight forward CSV, without any JSON

Comment: yeah its a csv i need to only take company names and the code gives the domain name which need to saved back to csv

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)` returns a dictionary, so you can access the values of it just like with any other python dictionary.  You don't care that it came from json, that's handled for you.  (also this question has nothing to do with csv).

Two other points:

- Publishing your authentication key to clearbit is probably a bad idea
- Publishing names and job titles of people in your csv file is probably a bad idea too, unless you've made all this data up.

Comment: can you tell me how to get that domain name i really confused as i am new to this

Comment: you already have `print(domain)`, what does that give you?  That should be the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, there are two things:

1. Extracting domain from the data returned by clearbit
2. Working with Pandas

---

1. Clearbit API returns a dictionary. You may simply do:

like this:

```
data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n)
print(data) # Dictionary
print(data['domain']) # Domain value
```

2. For working with Pandas, you don't loop on the data

Use apply

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def parse_url(x):
    return 'unknown' if pd.isnull(x) else urlparse(x)[1]

df = pd.read_csv("./new.csv")
df['domain'] = df['Profile URL'].apply(parse_url)
df_new = df.loc[:, ['Company', 'domain']]
```

### Edit:

Parser for clearbit could be implemented like (*I have not tried this code, but it should work*):

```
import clearbit
def parse_url(x):
    return 'unknown' if pd.isnull(x)

    data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=x)
    return data.get('domain', 'Default value')
```

> This code imports data from the CSV provided. You may instead call the clearbit API in the parse_url method and return appropriate value.
>
> This solution works on Python3. Please take it as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: if there is a none in the output,loop stops and throws error not so correct

Comment: For that you need to do `df.dropna()` to drop null values. Or check `x.isnull()` in the apply method.

Comment: no i cannot be dropped as it should be placed beside the corresponding company names in the csv !

Comment: If it cannot be dropped, you may return some default value from the method used in apply. Somewhere, you need to check for `isnull()`. Bottom-line - you should avoid writing loops when using Pandas. This is for better performance.

Comment: can you please edit your code so that i a can get you !

Comment: @vipul-rao, I have edited the `parse_url` method. Check it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: You may add the clearbit code in the `parse_url` method

Comment: @vipul-rao, I have added code for clearbit too. See if it helps.

Comment: i am totally confused i dont understand how this works can you paste the code you tired which works :/ need serious help

Comment: @vipul-rao, please share your contact number. I'll call you.

Comment: you there ? i am not able to fix this yet

Answer (score 0):

As it is a dictionary we can assign some default value to it and store in the csv file and later removing it does the job :)

**The edited code**

```
import pandas as pd
import clearbit
import json
clearbit.key = 'your key'
df = pd.read_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv", sep=',', encoding="utf-8")
saved_column = df['Company'].dropna()
i=0
res = []
for data in saved_column:   
    n = saved_column.get(i)
    print(n)
    i = i+1
    data = clearbit.NameToDomain.find(name=n) 
    if data != None: 
        res.append(data['domain'])
    else:
        res.append('domain.com')
print(res)
df['Domain'] = res
df.to_csv("/home/vipul/Desktop/new.csv",index = False, skipinitialspace=False)

print("File saved to desktop as new.csv")
```